# Printing PowerPoint slides as a poster

Tags: printing, microsoft-powerpoint, slideshow

I have 20 PowerPoint slides which I would like to print as an A0 poster with 5 rows/4 columns.

- The slides contain Math which becomes garbage if I export the slides into a Metafile.

  Printing into file only allows at most 9 slides per page.

Is there an alternative way of creating a poster?

Comment: If you open them in PowerPoint, you could Save as .jpg or .png and go from there. And if you have no PowerPoint, try the free Libre Office Impress.

Comment: Save from PPT as PDF.  Open the PDF in Acrobat or Reader.  In the print dialog, you can choose to print multiple pages per sheet ... you should be able to specify 5 x 4 there.